# How to resolve CultureNotFoundException in MVC 4 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have this filter in my MVC 4 application:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System;

namespace MvcApplication20.Filters
{
    public class CultureFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly string defaultCulture;

        public CultureFilter(string defaultCulture)
        {
            this.defaultCulture = defaultCulture;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var values = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

                string culture = (string)values["culture"] ?? this.defaultCulture;

                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Utility.Utility.WriteLineToConsole("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using routing to cover the localization of my application, so I need to have language part in the URL like for example:

```
http://localhost:5556/en/ControllerName/ControllerMethod
```

The problem is, if I accidentally remove the language part in the URL i.e the culture, I get **"Not Found"** page in the browser and in debug I get **CultureNotFoundException** with message: **"Culture is not supported."**.
Of course it cannot handle **ControllerName** as a culture/language.

Still, **"Not Found"** page doesn't tell you where the problem appeared.

What is the best way to notify me or the user that I or him misses the language part in the URL?

Does **CultureInfo** class has some specific way of dealing with unknown culture?

Comment: "Does CultureInfo class has some specific way of dealing with unknown culture?" Yes? It throws CultureNotFoundException..... I may just not understand this question.

Comment: Yes, I might have though, how should I pass data to my "Not Found" page to display the error that happened.

Comment: That will of course depend on that page, I can't answer that. Catch that specific exception and then in response show an appropriate error message and/or page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to some controller/action method by passing your error code and then in the error view check with that error code and show the error as 'Culture not found'.

In your catch block you can write like

```
context.Result = RedirectToRoute("StatusCodeRoute", new { statusCode = "1001" });
```

and then in StatusCode controller

```
[Route("/StatusCode/{statusCode}", Name = "StatusCodeRoute")]
        public IActionResult Index(int statusCode)
        {
           return View(statusCode);

        }
```

and your error view

```
@model int

    @{

        var statusCode = Model;

        var statusmessage = "";

        switch (statusCode)

        {

            case "1001":

                statusmessage = "Culture not found";

                break;


            default:

                statusmessage = "That’s odd... Something we didn't expect happened";

                break;

        }

    }

    <div class="jumbotron">

        <h1>Error @Model</h1>

        <h3>@statusmessage</h3>

    </div>
```